# UIViewController auto layout in iOS8

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios8.1

After updating device to iOS 8 the next issues with layout occur.

I have an UITabBarController which contains two UITableViewController embedded in UINavigationController. This is main view.

Also there are several UIViewControllers designed in StoryBoard (not embedded in UINavigationViewControllers). These are secondary views. All of them have "Hide Bottom bar on Push" set to YES. Constraints are set to determine layout.

All secondary views are shown with:
`UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_NAME bundle:nil];
UIViewController* secondaryView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:_name];
[navigationController pushViewController:secondaryView animated:YES];`

All works fine on iOS7.
But with iOS8 there are some problems when secondary view controller appears:

1. All pinned to bottom UIViews are shown on wrong places for a moment and then "jump" to correct place. Looks like first position is calculated including bottom bar (which is hidden due to "Hide on Push")
2. If there is UITableView as subview: top pinned subviews again are show on wrong place for a moment and then "jump" to correct place. Looks like first position is calculated not including navigation bar size. If i remove UITableView from controller - all works fine (except p.1)

Tried to set Simulated metrics for secondary views - did not help.

These "jumps" are really annoying. Would appreciate for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with jumping when hiding the tab bar from the Storyboard.
Make sure your bottom subviews are pinned to the superview rather than the Bottom Layout Constraint.

You have to do this from the `menu - Editor - Pin - Bottom Space to Superview`, because the `Auto Layout` menu in `Interface Builder` pins to `Bottom Layout Constraint` by default.

Comment: thx, the problem really was with pin but i've also removed UITabBarController and added just simple UIViewController with UITabbar

Answer (score 0):

As far as i experienced iOS 8 have issue in tabbar controller mixed with navigation bar controller .. removing one of them will make it run ok again.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need both of them.